# MYSQL limit the group by records fetch to 3

Tags: php

I want to limit the array to 3 which is been fetch used Group by.

The query is as below:

```
$sql_time = "SELECT date FROM tb_player_activity WHERE user_id='$data[1]' GROUP BY date DESC";
```

I want to display only 3 records of the array which is been fetched

Comment: You can simply use LIMIT 3

Comment: use LIMIT 3 to get only 3 record

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql limit

```
$sql_time = "SELECT date FROM tb_player_activity WHERE user_id='$data[1]' GROUP BY date DESC limit 3";
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use LIMIT

```
$sql_time = "SELECT date FROM tb_player_activity 
              WHERE user_id='$data[1]' 
              GROUP BY date DESC 
              LIMIT 3";
```

> MySQL LIMIT Clause. In MySQL the LIMIT clause is used with the SELECT
>   statement to restrict the number of rows in the result set. The Limit
>   Clause accepts one or two arguments which are offset and count.The
>   value of both the parameters can be zero or positive integers.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date FROM tb_player_activity WHERE user_id='$data[1]' GROUP BY date DESC limit 0,3
```

**Note**: Passing the paramters like this would lead to SQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

try limit for it:

```
$sql_time = "SELECT date FROM tb_player_activity WHERE user_id='$data[1]' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3";
```